# How can be the the cache expire date be in 1978 while the data is fetched in 2017?

Tags: http

I was using fiddler to capture the HTTP traffic to see what happens behind the scenes.

While going through the server response. I found the following in the cache header part.

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 17:16:33 GMT
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
```

How can the expiry data b earlier than that of the data fetched date?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/1968624

Comment: That may certainly be possible, why not? It has been specified that way. Most likely by sloppy programming, the published wanted to specify a relative timespan which is not possible or simply forgot/failed to add two dates...

Comment: @arkascha but having an expiry date earlier than that of the fetching date, it will mean that that the cache data wont ever expire. Will this be the case ?

Comment: In contrary, it is always already expired. In fact that is a standard way to suppress caching.

Comment: @arkascha if the above method was used to suppress caching why cannot one directly use the no-cache directive in the header.

Comment: The recommended way to disable client side caching is to apply severy means at the same time in case some browser does not recognize one of them. Keep in mind that "the web" is a very diverse and moving target to send information to.

Comment: But considering the strange 5 hours that got specify I am not certain this is such an attempt. That is why I wrote my first comment. Could be sloppy programming.

Comment: @arkascha Got it ! thanks a lot

Comment: @arkascha I want to clear one more thing. The data is fetched from the web site has an expiry date earlier than that of the fetching date. So will some browsers dump the data simply because of the expiry date or they will just dump the cache data?

Comment: Those headers only control the cache. That has nothing to do with using and visualizing the data in the first place. Consider this: _all_ data received from some http server has expired since it is a picture of the past when you receive it...

Comment: @arkascha Okay. Got it